# Binding a Viewbox to a Canvas

Tags: wpf, canvas, binding

I'm trying to bind a `Viewbox` to a `Canvas` that is created dynamically like so:

```
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DockPanel>
                    <Viewbox>
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Canvas}"/>
                    </Viewbox>
                </DockPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

This works fine as long as the `Canvas` doesn't have any children, but as soon at the `Canvas` has children it's not shown. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

How do you know it works? A `Canvas` is just a `Panel` with zero width/height. Even if it has any children, its dimensions are still going to be 0,0. You must explicitly set `Width` and `Height` to a non-zero value in order for it to appear. Paste the following snippet into `XamlPad` or just test in your own app. Now, remove either `Width` or `Height` and it will vanish.

```
<Viewbox>
   <ContentPresenter>
      <ContentPresenter.Content>
         <Canvas Background="Red" Width="1" Height="1">
            <TextBlock Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="20" Text="123" />
         </Canvas>
      </ContentPresenter.Content>
   </ContentPresenter>
</Viewbox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Forget I ever asked :-)

I caused an exception when creating the children of canvas, and this in turn caused the canvas to not be shown. I'm sad to say that it's not the first time I have made this mistake, and it's probably not that last time either:

```
TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
tb.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, 5);
tb.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, 5);
```

"5" is not a valid value for 'Left' or 'Top'. It should of course be

```
TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
tb.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, 5.0);
tb.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, 5.0);
```

And because it was created as part of data binding, no exception dialog was shown. All in all ... DOOOOH :-)
:-)